# How to compute $I_n= \int_{0}^{\pi/4} x\tan^{2n}x\, \mathrm{d}x $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

Consider the following integral

$$I_n= \int_{0}^{\pi/4} x\tan^{2n}x \, \mathrm{d}x $$

Then compute $I_n + I_{n+1}$ as a function of $n$ $\forall n\geq0$.

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, notice that

$$\begin{align}
I_n + I_{n+1} &= \int_{0}^{\pi/4} x \left( \tan^{2n}x +\tan^{2n+2}x \right) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_{0}^{\pi/4} x\tan^{2n}x \left(1+ \tan^2 x\right) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_{0}^{\pi/4} x\tan^{2n}x \, \sec^2 x \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \dfrac{1}{2n+1} x \tan^{2n+1} x |_{0}^{\pi/4} - \dfrac{1}{2n+1} \int_{0}^{\pi/4} \tan^{2n+1}x \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \dfrac{1}{2n+1} \left( \dfrac{\pi}{4} - \int_{0}^{\pi/4} \tan^{2n+1}x \, \mathrm{d}x \right) \\
&\equiv \dfrac{1}{2n+1} \left( \dfrac{\pi}{4} - J_n \right)
\end{align}$$

and for computing $J_n$ I refer you to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226785/computing-i-n-int-tanxn-mathrm-dx). For the sake of completeness, I just mention the final result

$$\begin{align}
J_n &=\int_{0}^{\pi/4} \tan x ^{2n+1} \mathrm dx \\
&= \left[ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^k}{2(n-k)}\tan x ^{2(n-k)}+(-1)^{n+1}\ln \cos x \right]_{0}^{\pi/4} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^k}{2(n-k)}+\frac{(-1)^n}{2}\ln2
\end{align}$$

and hence

$$\boxed{
I_n + I_{n+1} = \dfrac{1}{2n+1} \left( \dfrac{\pi}{4} - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^k}{2(n-k)}-\frac{(-1)^n}{2}\ln2 \right)
}$$

Comment: what about the convergence of $(I_n)_{n \in N}$ ?

Comment: @John Do you mean $\lim_{n \to \infty} I_n$ exist or not? If so, I think it is better to look at $I_n= \int_{0}^{\pi/4} x\tan^{2n}x\, \mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: yes i mean $\lim I_n$

Comment: @John: Take a look at [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202418/compute-lim-n-to-infty-int-0-pi-4-tann-x-dx?rq=1).

Comment: i understand, thank you

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**
$$
\tan^{2n}(x)+\tan^{2n+2}(x)=\tan^{2n}(x)\sec^2(x)
$$
and
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\tan(x)=\sec^2(x)
$$
Try integrating by parts.

Comment: I have to compute $I_n + I_{n+1}$ as a fonction of $n$. We have $I_n + I_{n+1}= \frac{\pi}{4(2n+1)} + \frac{1}{2n+1} \int_{0}^{\pi/4} tan^{2n+1}(x) \, \mathrm{d}x $ . How can i continue ?

Comment: @John: Take a look at my answer. :)

Comment: @H. R. i understand , thanks

Comment: given $\pi/4 > \epsilon > 0$, How can we show that :
$$\int_0^{\pi/4} \tan^n x\ dx < (\pi/4 - \epsilon) \tan(\pi/4 - \epsilon)^n + \epsilon $$ ?